# Looking for proper hbase-site.xml hbase-default.xml config example for HBase client

Tags: api, configuration, client, hbase

I am trying to connect to an HBase node from a Java application. HBaseConfiguration is key, but the available Javadoc and documentation is really poor and insufficient.

Does anyone have proper examples of hbase-site.xml hbase-default.xml to use for remote connection?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the steps from my setup doc about the `hbase-site.xml`. We don't make any changes to the `hbase-default.xml` as ... well... that's all the default settings. :)

1. edit hbase-site.xml. Copy the following to the file.

> <?xml version="1.0"?>
>   <?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl"
>   href="configuration.xsl"?>
>   <configuration>
>         <property>
>                 <name>hbase.rootdir</name>              <value>hdfs://PDHadoop1.corp.COMPANY.com:54310/usr/hbase</value>
>                 <final>true</final>         </property>
>         <property>
>                 <name>hbase.zookeeper.quorum</name>
>   <value>PDHadoop1.corp.COMPANY.com,PDHadoop2.corp.COMPANY.com,PDHadoop3.corp.COMPANY.com,PDHadoop4.corp.COMPANY.com</value>
>                 <final>true</final>         </property>
>         <property>
>                 <name>hbase.cluster.distributed</name>
>                 <value>true</value>
>                 <final>true</final>         </property>
>   </configuration>

1. Save the file and quit the editor.
2. Please note that hbase.rootdir is pointing to PDHadoop1 as that is the name node in development environment. Similarly, hbase.zookeeper.quorum is pointing to all zookeeper servers in development environment. Please substitute these values with appropriate server names in your environment.
3. edit regionservers. Copy the following to the file.

`PDHadoop3.corp.COMPANY.com

PDHadoop2.corp.COMPANY.com

PDHadoop1.corp.COMPANY.com`

I apologize for the XML's lack of formatting.

These are the settings we use in production, I opened the file on my dev cluster to verify.

I hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks. In fact, I have used a simpler version of your hbase-site.xml where I only set the hbase.rootdir property. My application manages to connect.

Comment: I am copying my hbase-site.xml here (REM: I have added a property to indicate that my node operates in standalone mode): <?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>hbase.zookeeper.quorum</name>
        <value>your.node.ip.address</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>hbase.cluster.distributed</name>
        <value>false</value>
    </property>
</configuration>

Answer (score 2):

There are only two variables you need to set from a clients point of view:

> hbase.rootdir
>
> hbase.zookeeper.quorum

Answer (score 1):

One major gotcha that I've encountered is that if your /etc/hosts contains an entry for that hostname pointing to the loopback address (127.0.0.1, 127.0.1.1, et cetra), then Hbase master will incorrectly register itself in Zookeeper with that loopback address -- which will not work when your client is not on the same machine as your master.

I wasted quite a bit of time to (first) get Hbase working.  The solution is to remove the entry in /etc/hosts; but this requires that you override the "out of the box" behavior of the OS, at least on the ubuntu box that I've tested this on...